# Change the toolbar title during execution Android

Tags: android

When I start the app I want to display the app name as a placeholder. After getting the user's info, I want to change the title to a variable related to this user.

If I initially do this:

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And then after a while do this:

```
toolbar.setTitle(user.getName());
```

It works fine.

But! If instead of setting the title to an empty string I set it to a non empty string it doesn't work. I assume Android is checking if the title is empty before placing it or something. Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` again after setting toolbar title with user's name.

```
    toolbar.setTitle(user.getName());
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: It should work but if you use `Android Navigation` then you should also use this `setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)` line after above solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use :

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("New title");
```

and it works. Give it a try.

Comment: This only works if the first setTitle is of an empty string. If the first setTitle is of a non empty string or of a resource id the second setTitle doesn't work. I've tried it the way you suggested and it doesn't change.